# Hibernate/JPA Update query fails

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sql-update

Good afternoon,

I don't know why this query is giving an exception, could someone please help me to understand?

**Code**

```
@PUT
@Path("/process")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response processEreturn(List<Long> ereturns){

    EntityManager em = Utils.initEntityManager();

    Query q = em.createQuery("UPDATE ereturn e SET e.processedByShipper = true WHERE e.id = 111713");

    q.executeUpdate();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

**Excepion**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-servlet] in context with path [/returnitRest] threw exception [javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query] with root cause
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1492)
    at returnitRest.EreturnResource.processEreturn(EreturnResource.java:954)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)   

thank you very much
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad, I forgot to start the transaction.

this the solution:

```
@PUT
@Path("/process")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response processEreturn(List<Long> ereturns){

    EntityManager em = Utils.initEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Query q = em.createQuery("UPDATE ereturn e SET e.processedByShipper = true WHERE e.id = 111713");

    q.executeUpdate();

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```